# How to Use JSON object for Bootstrap Tree instead of a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Bootstrap Tree](https://github.com/cutterbl/Bootstrap-Tree) to construct a tree control.
You can use a JSON file as the source for tree nodes. All you need to do is this ([Source](https://github.com/cutterbl/Bootstrap-Tree/blob/master/index.html)):

```
<li><a href="jsonexample.json" role="branch" class="tree-toggle closed" data-toggle="branch" data-value="JSON_Example">JSON Ajax Example</a></li>
```

My question is: How can I use a JSON object as the source of the tree instead of a JSON file?

Comment: Where is bootstrap tree documented?

Comment: Sadly, there isn't much documentation beyond the github page which I've just referenced. It has some samples.

Comment: Where did you generate the JSON object ? Server-side or Client-Side ?

Comment: If there's a way for me (using Javascript) to write the JSON object to a JSON file and use the sample as it is, then that might work.

Comment: JSON object generated on the client-side by calling other external servers (not the server serving the page).

Comment: The plugin is written in such a way that it simply isnt possible to not use an external location for the json without modifying/extending the plugin. https://github.com/cutterbl/Bootstrap-Tree/blob/master/bootstrap-tree/js/bootstrap-tree.js

Comment: To modify the plugin, I need to start at line 95 here https://github.com/cutterbl/Bootstrap-Tree/blob/master/bootstrap-tree/js/bootstrap-tree.js to add option to just receive a JSON object instead of a document, correct?

Comment: you would need to start on line 88, add an if statement that will contain the $.post if an href was provided, else take the json from `y` and use it instead.

Comment: Or, maybe even do the work on line 59

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the click event will make a call to the href. It's a post request, passing in any parameters from the data api. So, if the href="mydynamic.cfc" data-method="myjsongenmethod" data-id="someidvalue" data-returnformat="json", then it will perform a jQuery ajax POST, passing a data object of {"method": "myjsongenmethod", "id": "someidvalue", "returnformat": "json"} to your server-side temmplate of "mydynamic.cfc" (or whatever other server-side you want). It will expect your return format to be like what you see in that example json doc.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this is a reallllllyyyy early version of this plugin, which is why I haven't created a demo site or documentation yet. I think the entire api may change in the future. I want to keep it simple, and in the same overall fashion as the core Bootstrap components.

Comment: Any progress on Bootstrap-Tree?  It looks useful.

Comment: 0 down vote
 

Not yet, but I will be digging in again real soon. Had a side contract taking all available free time, but I've got a little more time now to look into it.